# Google search is not showing my site in search results

Tags: seo, google-search

I have created my self a small website for converting ebooks and documents between different formats. It seems that Google is not relating my website with any keywords. The site is for sure indexed by google but it seams like google does not know what the site is about. As a result it is not showing in google searches. Would it be possible that I get some suggestions on how to make google aware of the content of the site. Any suggestion is welcomed as I'm really a beginner in SEO.